# Adding a character at the end of text & increment letter A to B

Tags: vba, excel, loops, increment

What I need help on is to *copy the previous cells text into the cell below it* and *add the letter `A` at the end of it*  i.e. before `VP0007` after `VP0007A`. This should continue until all the blank cells have been incremented and it reaches the next `VP0008`.

Please see the images. I apologise if I am not too clear.

**Before:**                              **After:**
     [image: before]    [image: after]

Right now I have the following code:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Letter = "A" 
Letters = Chr(Asc(Letter) + 1) 
Number = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value 
If ActiveCell.Value = Number & Letter _ Then 
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select.Value Number & Number 
Else 
    ActiveCell.Value = Number & Letters 
End If 
Loop Until ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value <> ""
```

Comment: What have you done so far and where exactly do you have problems?

Comment: I've copied the wrong image. if you have a look at the image which i have re-uploaded it should show you.

Comment: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Letter = "A"
Letters = Chr(Asc(Letter) + 1)
Number = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value

If ActiveCell.Value = Number & Letter _
Then
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select.Value Number & Number

Else
ActiveCell.Value = Number & Letters
End If
Loop Until ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value <> ""

Comment: Please put any new information about your question (such as that code) into the question itself. You are encouraged to [edit] it to add more information.  Also make sure to format code properly. (Highlight it and click the `{  }` button on the [Edit Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49611956/edit) toolbar.) Also, you can edit comments for up to 5 minutes after you write them.

Comment: Sorry Ashlee, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should handle cases where you have more than 26 blank rows and increment past the letter "Z".

```
Sub FillBlanks()

Dim lastRow As Long, cnt As Long, i As Long
Dim prevItem As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
prevItem = ws.Cells(2, 1).Value
cnt = 0

For i = 2 To lastRow

  If ws.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
    cnt = cnt + 1
    ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = prevItem & Split(Cells(1, cnt).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
  Else
    prevItem = ws.Cells(i, 1)
    cnt = 0
  End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this short sub procedure.

```
Sub fillSubseries()
    Dim i As Long, a As Long, str As String

    With Worksheets("sheet4")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, "A")) Then
                .Cells(i, "A") = str & Chr(a)
                a = a + 1
            Else
                a = 65
                str = .Cells(i, "A").Value2
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Letter = "A"
For iLoop = 2 To LastRow
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & iLoop) = "" Then
        iValue = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & iLoop - 1)
        iiLoop = iLoop
        Do
            If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & iiLoop) = "" Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("A" & iiLoop) = iValue & Letter
                Letter = Chr(Asc(Letter) + 1)
            Else
                Letter = "A"
                Exit Do
            End If
            iiLoop = iiLoop + 1
        Loop
        iLoop = iiLoop - 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Jeeped your code is giving me symbols and mmehta after i have signed variables to them it didn't like this row {iValue = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & iLoop - 1)} but thanks for your help

Comment: mmehta your code was effective after i had a bit of a play around with it. When the letters increment all the way to Z, how can i start the next cell (the next blank cell) with AB instead of it going to symbols? Can you please advise?

Comment: Good to know. Please mark it as correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternate:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sLetter As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
        aData = .Value
    End With

    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
        If Len(Trim(aData(i, 1))) > 0 Then
            sTemp = Trim(aData(i, 1))
            j = 0
        Else
            j = j + 1
            sLetter = Replace(ws.Cells(1, j).Address(0, 0), 1, vbNullString)
            aData(i, 1) = sTemp & sLetter
        End If
    Next i

    ws.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(aData, 1)).Value = aData

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a pure formula solution, you may try below steps (The first row of your data should be A2, not A1):

1. First we need a dummy column in order to fill in the blank rows. Use below formula on B2 and copy it down through the last row of column A:

   ```
   =IF(A2<>"",A2,B1)
   ```
2. Then we will create the final values on column C. Add below formula to C2 and copy down:

   ```
   =IF(A2<>"",A2,IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(RIGHT(C1,1)))=TRUE,C1&"A",B2&CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(C1,1))+1)))
   ```

Basically we first filled in the blank rows with repeating values on column B. Then copied Col:A value to Col:C if Col:A is not blank. If Col:A is blank and upper row (Col:C) value's last character is numeric we add "A" to that value. If the last character is a letter than we concatenate the next letter with Col:B value.

You should have something like below, when everything is OK:

[image: final view]

Comment: Andrew your vba code worked like a charm. Thank you very much and everyone else who has helped me out.